# Prove that this function is Borel Measurable.

Tags: borel-measures

I have this function and I want to prove it is Borel measurable. 
$$\begin{equation}
f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\sin(\frac{1}{x-y}) &\text{ for } x>y \\\
x^2+y^2 &\text{ for } x\leq y 
\end{cases}\end{equation}$$
I thought you could start with only looking at the first part (so for $x>y$) and then the other part. Because if they were both Borel measurable then the function is too. But now I don't know how to do them apart.

Comment: How about using the characteristic functions of the sets $A= \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, x > y\}$ and $B = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\, x \leq y\}$

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: For $A$ and $B$ as avove, let $\mathbf{1}_A$ be the function that is $1$ on $A$ and zero on its complement. Same for $\mathbf{1}_B$. Then, your function can be written using these functions, as sum, product and compositions of measurable functions. This is essentially Kavi Rama Murthy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(x,y)=\frac 1 {x-y}$ if $x >y$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $f(x,y)=\sin (h(x,y))I_A(x,y)+(x^{2}+y^{2})I_B$ where $A=\{(x,y): x>y\}$ and $B=\{(x,y): x\leq y\}$. Since products of Borel measurable functions, compositions of Borel measurable functions  and sums of Borel measurable are Borel measurable it is enough  it is enough to check that $h$ is Borel measurable. For this it is enough to check that $\{(x,y): h(x,y) <a\}$ is measurable for any $a \geq 0$ I will leave this last part to you.

Comment: I understand that you can split that function into two different functions. Then you need to prove that they are Borel measurabel. How do you prove that for g(x,y)=$sin(1/(x-y))$ for x>y and h(x,y)=$x^{2}+y^{2}$ for x<y?

Comment: @wisk First check that $h$ is measurable. Then conclude that $\sin (h(x,y)$ is measurable. It then follows that $\sin (h(x,y)I_B(x,y)$ is measurable.